# Insert into datagridview column specific values in vb net

Tags: vb.net

i am developing an app for windows in vb net.
I am stuck in the last part which is the following and i would like some help on to where should i look or do.My question:I have one database in mysql called patient.each patient have the usual columns(name,surname etc..).Apart from all the columns there is one column called 'time' and another one called 'date'.I have also one datagrid where these values are displayed.When a new user is to be added,all the fields are filled and in the 'time' he fills the time of visit.I would like to ask if there is any way to restrict the range of time according to date...for example to be able in the beginning before adding the new patient,to say that in august 30 of 2014 the range of time for appointments is from 9 to 10.So when the new patient is added on that date ,to book only between this range every  ten minutes eg 9:10,then 9:20 and so on until 10.

I am really stuck and been searching the last week for a solution ,so any ideas on the implementation would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance..If you need some of my code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the input data, you have to use the `DataGridView`'s `CellValidating` event. There you can check wether the input is ok or not. If it's not ok, you can set the `ErrorText` field of the edited row, where you can explain to the user what's wrong with his input.

Have a look at this [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ehy30d4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the MSDN.